# AWS Amplify - 404 error when deploying Nextjs App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy a Nextjs (v12) to Amplify.

All the checkmarks are green, but when I visit the URL (provided by AWS), it 404.

My build settings :

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
        commands:
            - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run buildamp
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

The command `npm run buildamp` is simply `next build`

The build directory is indeed .next. I have no /src directory.

The App is quite big and old, with both TS and JS files. There are some dubious settings in tsconfig.json, jsconfig.json and next.config files.

What should I look into to find the source of the error ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this problem, this was fixed by :

- setting the app platform to WEB_COMPUTE :

`aws amplify update-app --app-id <APP_ID> --platform WEB_COMPUTE --region <REGION>`

- setting each branch to framework 'Next.js - SSR' :

`aws amplify update-branch --app-id <APP_ID> --branch-name <BRANCH_NAME> --framework 'Next.js - SSR' --region <REGION>`

Comment: Whenever I deploy my NextJS app (using app directory) with amplify, I get 304 and a blank page and it fixes it self after a while, any idea?
Platform is WEB_COMPUTE and framework is Next.js SSR as seen in aws